# How do I format date in Discord.js v12 as DD/MMM/YYYY

Tags: date, datetime, formatting, discord, discord.js

I want to format date in an info command as DD/MMM/YYYY but I keep getting an error

Here's the code:

```js
switch(args[1]) {
    case 'info':

        let user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
        let member = msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.member;
        const created = (user.createdAt).format("DD, MMM Do YYYY");
        const join = (member.joinedAt).format("DD, MMM Do YYYY");
        const infoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colour)
        .setTitle('__Info __')
        .setDescription('')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Joined discord:', value: created, inline: true},
            { name: 'Joined server:', value: join, inline: true},
        )
msg.channel.send(infoEmbed)
}
```

And here's the error in the console:

```js
const created = (user.createdAt).format("DD, MMM Do YYYY");
                                         ^

TypeError: user.createdAt.format is not a function
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oq1z.png) an image of the embed without `.format("DD, MMM Do YYYY")` which is what I'm trying to avoid

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please explain it to me.
(I'm using Visual Studio Code if that's important)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using https://npmjs.com/package/moment for this? I don't believe date objects have a `format` method by default.

Comment: I'm very new to coding so I don't really know. Can you explain it like your talking to a child because I don't really understand the terminology that much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an NPM package named [moment](https://npmjs.com/package/moment) to format dates easily, which appears to be what you're missing. You presumably installed discord.js with the following command:
`$ npm install discord.js`

To install moment, just run the exact same command but replacing `discord.js` with `moment`. This will install the package you need.

At the top of your code in the same file, write the following line:

```
const moment = require('moment');
```

This 'requires' the `moment` module, giving you access to its exports (functions, classes, etc) so you can use it in your code.

Using moment to format dates is easy and straightforward. In this scenario, we're formatting a Discord user's `createdAt` property, which is a date object:

```
const created = moment(user.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY');
```

This should result in what you're looking for.

Comment: `moment` is deprecated. it's not getting any maintenance.